# cognos (/p2pd/servlet/dispatch) is not available

Tags: cognos

I downloaded and installed Cognos BI latest version 10.2.1 the trialversion i'm not sure if it's ok or not as it's my first time to proccess this version and trial on windows environment I'm not able to find the configuration under IBM cognos Business intelligence developer trial folder i only have framework manager , cognos bi and manager console  and map manager

when i open IBM cogno BI it open browser with following error:
HTTP Status 404 - /p2pd/servlet/dispatch

---

type Status report

message /p2pd/servlet/dispatch

description The requested resource (/p2pd/servlet/dispatch) is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

also under services the service of cognos is up

not sure where to start from any hints

Comment: check in `<cognos install location>/logs`, loook for `cogserver.log`.

Comment: What is exact path in your browser? Have you configured IIS? Cognos BI portal URL is usually: http:// localhost/ibmcognos10/ it may be a bit longer with "/cgi-bin/cognos.cgi" after this URL. This is default configuration.